# How to get full server name by sql query on azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

How to get full server name using sql query on azure sql db. I am getting database name but not getting full server name.

output gives just database name but server name is *****.database.windows.net, and i am not getting second part '.database.windows.net' by query.

select SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS InstanceName

expected : Example.database.windows.net
actual : Example

Comment: just concat the rest? its always .database.windows.net

Comment: Assuming you’re not connecting to a database in Azure Sovereign cloud. In that case, append the suffix accordingly.

Comment: I HV us and China both, so extension also I need by query.

Comment: As other have already mentioned append the suffix. SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') is the property that gives the server name.

Comment: I have two environment USA and China, so I can not appended anything. I need to know in which environment I am at run time and set default value for a column.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

The `ServerName` property of the `SERVERPROPERTY` function and @@SERVERNAME return similar information. The ServerName property provides the Windows server and instance name that together make up the unique server instance.

[image]

It's return type is `sql_variant`.

I tried this by appending the suffix. So I have to convert the datatype. To see my sql.

**My SQL**:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(nvarchar(50),SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')),'.database.windows.net') as FullServerName;
```

**Result**:
[image]

I get the result like you expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have two environment USA and China, so I can not appended anything. I need to know in which environment I am at run time and set default value for a column.

Comment: @VatanSoni You have two environment USA and China, do they use different Azure SQL database? The result of the query just show the full server name like you expected, not modify the column value. It seems that what  you want to know is an another new different question.Just get the full Azure SQL server name could not help you know which environment you am at run time.Maybe you can repost a new question, others can help you.

Comment: Yes they use different Azure SQL database.
one extension is .net and other is .cn.
I have common alter table script which should add a new column and add default value based on if its .net or .cn

Comment: Use select SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') only can get the Azure database instance name. Your two  environment  are use different databases, they also have different instance names in usual. I think you can know the environment you're in by using the SQL database instance name, don't you? In this case, whether you know the full server name may not have an impact. You can add a new column and add default value based on if its instance name.

Comment: @VatanSoni  Can you do like this?